# Multiple jQuery sliders: How to disable keyboard navigation for all but one slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have six sliders on a single page, each in its own section. As you scroll, the section in view gets a CSS class of 'active.' I'm trying to disable keyboard navigation for every slider except the slider in the active section.

My current code looks like this:

```js
$('section').not('.active').on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 37 || e.keyCode === 39) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

No avail. They all move. Is my selector wrong? Is there a better way to disable left and right keyboard navigation for a group of elements?

I'm using [Unslider](http://unslider.com/).

Comment: which slider plugin you use?

Comment: [Unslider](http://unslider.com/).

Comment: can you share the code which you used to initialize the slider.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Cerlin Boss for the help! Here's the solution I ended up using, including arrow navigation that works for individual sliders on a multi-slider page:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.portfolio-slider').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.unslider({
          delay: false,
          dots: false,
          fluid: true,
          keys: true,
          loop: true
        }).find('.unslider-arrow').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
                $this.data('unslider').next();
            } else {
                $this.data('unslider').prev();
            }
        });
        $(document).unbind('keydown').keydown(function(e){
            var active = $('div.portfolio-slider.active');
            if(e.keyCode === 37 ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                active.data('unslider').prev();
                return false;
            }
            if(e.keyCode === 39 ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                active.data('unslider').next();
                return false;
            }
        });

    });
});
```

The key, as Cerlin Boss pointed out, is to unbind keydown events, and then rebind them to target only the slider with a specific class, in my case 'active'. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `keydown` event is assigned to `document` so first you have to unbind the existing event assigned by the plugin and bind a new keydown event which changes the slide on `next` and `prev`.

If you have used `$('.banner').unslider();` (ie. a css selector to select all sliders) to initialize the sliders then the following code will do the job

```
$(function() {
    var banners = $('.banner');
    banners.unslider();
    $(document).unbind('keydown').keydown(function(e){
        var index = banners.index($('.active')[0]) + 1;
        var data = $('.active').data('unslider'+index);

        if(e.keyCode === 37 ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            data.prev();
            return false;
        }
        if(e.keyCode === 39 ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            data.next();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Sample [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/osLufyek/)

**UPDATE**

I have made a small correction in the selector for active banner

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/pwj3ty1k/13/)

As you can see I have changed `$('.active')` to `$('div.active')`

I would recommend you to put a very specific class name than `active`

you can even replace `$('div.active')` with `$('div.portfolio-slider.active')`

Comment: Thanks so much!

unbind('keydown') is doing the trick, but I still can't get unslider navigation to bind! I can add in addClass and removeClass to change the background color of the div on keydown, so it's obviously working up to that point.

I'm using your code verbatim. I've tried setting sections and '.banner' divs to '.active' across the board for testing purposes. I've spent hours trying to figure this out. Any further ideas?

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle or something.?

Comment: give `active` class to the slider which you want the navigation

Comment: Of course, sorry, this is my first time on here. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanmaher/pwj3ty1k/12/) The PanelSnap plugin is acting kind of funny on there, but you can use the up and down keys to move the active section/div combo.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your help! For some reason I couldn't get your solution to work on my site, but as you can see what I ended up using was just a modification of this. Thanks again buddy!